# how to solve error in command "python systrace.py --set-tags gfx,view,wm"?

Tags: android, python, exception, command-line-arguments, android-sdk-tools

i want to do this:-

```
$> cd android-sdk/tools/systrace
$> python systrace.py --set-tags gfx,view,wm
$> adb shell stop
$> adb shell start
$> python systrace.py --disk --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html
```

i run this command:-

```
python systrace.py --set-tags gfx,view,wm
```

and error comes :-

```
set-tags gfx,view,wm
  File "systrace.py", line 91
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i dont have much idea of python script, Please Help.

Reference Link : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html#tags

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That script was written for python 2. You should install python 2.x, not python 3.x.

Android docs should have mentioned it by now, really.

Comment: when i run this "python systrace.py --disk --time=10 -o mynewtrace.html" this new error comes "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "systrace.py", line 280, in <module>
    main()
  File "systrace.py", line 155, in main
    ready = select.select([adb.stdout, adb.stderr], [], [adb.stdout, adb.stderr]
)
select.error: (10093, 'Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAS
tartup failed')"

Comment: hi, Pavel thanks for your help in changing version of python 3.x to 2.x

Comment: @pavel Is that working on Python 2.7 ? Here the error File "systrace.py", line 274, in <module>
    main()
  File "systrace.py", line 63, in main
    os.execv(legacy_script, sys.argv)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/, currently the correct syntax is **as** instead of the comma. Try changing the line:

```
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
```

to:

```
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
```

Comment: You can't expect him to port a tool from the android sdk to python 3 if he's unfamiliar with python. There are probably plenty of other problems.